# Searchbar is not refreshing the search when changing search string

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

I am trying to implement a searchbar to search after collection view items for item name.

This my code so far:

```
    var filtrados = false

  func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {



      if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
          filtrados = false
          marcasCV.reloadData()
      }
      else {

          filtrados = true
          let buscado = searchBar.text!.lowercased()
        print(marcas)
          marcas = marcas.filter {marcas in
                           return (marcas.nombre.lowercased().contains(buscado)   )
          }

         marcasCV.reloadData()
      }

  }

  func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
       filtrados = false
       marcasCV.reloadData()


  }
```

This is making the search and filtering the searched items.

My issue is that if I removed some search charachters or click the cancel button the search is not executed again, and the first searched items remain at the collection view.

Comment: issue is in this condition filtrados = true & if condition
When you change remove one or two characters from search text you condition remains true & you text is neither nil not empty
Why you are using condition ?
```
if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" 
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are overwriting your variable `marcas`. You are setting the filtered array to the same variable, so when your searchBar text is empty. The filtered array would be empty, and so would your variable `marcas`. What you have to do is create two variables:
i.e

```swift
var marcas = [YourStruct]()
var marcasFiltradas = [YourStruct]()
```

So then you would change your filtering line to this:

```swift
marcasFiltradas = marcas.filter {$0.nombre.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()}
```

And you would change your collectionView methods to something like this:

```swift
extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        filtrados ? marcasFiltradas.count : marcas.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let marca = filtrados ? marcasFiltradas[indexPath.row] : marcas[indexPath.row]
        // your code
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: please, let me check my new code with your proposal

Comment: I have implemented both arrays:  
     var marcas = [Marcas]() / 
     var marcasFiltradas: [Marcas] = [Marcas]()

Comment: @mvasco Would you like to create a chat?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I have another issue with the same proposal.

Comment: all what we have solved yesterday works fine, but now on clicking on an item the app throws an exception

Comment: 2020-04-28 18:29:14.484918+0200 Jogua[2937:102059] -[Jogua.NuevaAlarma2ViewController collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa93143e140
2020-04-28 18:29:14.490095+0200 Jogua[2937:102059] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Jogua.NuevaAlarma2ViewController collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa93143e140'

Comment: I guess the problem lies at method: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath

Answer (score 1):

```
  func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
          marcas = searchText.isEmpty ? marcasFiltradas : marcasFiltradas.filter({(marcasName: Marcas) -> Bool in
          // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
            return marcasName.name?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
         })

         marcasCV.reloadData()
     }

     func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
         searchBar.text = ""

         marcas = marcasFiltradas

         searchBar.endEditing(true)

         marcasCV.reloadData()
     }
```

Comment: what is searchdata in your proposal?

Comment: It's a copy of data array in which you will search data and remove the other which doesn't match with text.

Comment: In other words it's copy of same array in which you will find all data.

Comment: I have created another data array named marcasfiltradas. Would you mind to show me how to do it completely?

Comment: There are other errors on your code, like data model.

Comment: Can you provide declaration of marcas?

Comment: var marcas = [Marcas]()

Comment: var marcasFiltradas: [Marcas] = [Marcas]()

Comment: please check updated code if you still have any issue come to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212578/discussion-between-mvasco-and-muhammad-hasan-irshad).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do the search bar check inside searchbar delegate didchangetext method, what i do normally is creating the functionality inside collectionView delegate, if searchbar is nill then reload with the main array, if not nill then fill a new array with original array contained searchbar text, then you only need to implement inside didchangetext a collectionView reload method. Will provide you with code soon.

Comment: Thank you, I will wait for your proposal.

Comment: That's what I provided.